# Timestamp project - Unexpected Output After Using Regular Expressions

Tags: node.js, express, rest

I'm completing the FreeCodeCamp TimeStamp API project and had previously validated the time entered using Moment.js, but switched to using Regex because I believe the use of Moment is causing the app to fail the criteria to pass even though it worked. I want to be able to use the Regular Expressions, but for some reason the cause the wrong output. Here is a link to find the criteria for the app: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/back-end-development-and-apis/back-end-development-and-apis-projects/timestamp-microservice

Here is the code that I have for my app so far. Im using Node.js and Express through Replit:

```
// index.js
// where your node app starts

// init project
var express = require('express');
var moment = require('moment');
var app = express();

// enable CORS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)
// so that your API is remotely testable by FCC 
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({optionsSuccessStatus: 200}));  // some legacy browsers choke on 204

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
app.use(express.static('public'));

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

// your first API endpoint... 
app.get("/api/hello", function (req, res) {
  res.json({greeting: 'hello API'});
});

app.get("/api/:date?", function (req, res) {
 // Check if the entered param format is correct
  std = moment(req.params.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid()
  un = moment.unix(req.params.date, true).isValid()

  //Validation

  //Handling Standard Date Parameters:
  let stdDate = new Date(req.params.date);
  let unix_std = stdDate.getTime()
  let utc_std = stdDate.toUTCString()
  
  //Handling Millisecond Date Parameters:
  let milliDate = new Date(parseInt(req.params.date));
  let unix_milli = milliDate.getTime()
  let utc_milli = milliDate.toUTCString()

  //Handling Empty Date Parameters:
  let emptyDate = new Date();
  let unix_empty = emptyDate.getTime()
  let utc_empty = emptyDate.toUTCString()
  

  regex_std = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/gm
  regex_un = /\d{0,}/gm
  //console.log(regex_std.test(req.params.date))
  //console.log(regex_un.test(req.params.date))
  
  if (regex_std) {
    console.log('Valid STD Date!!')
    res.json({unix: unix_std, utc: utc_std})
  } else if (regex_un) {
    console.log('Valid UN Date!!')
    res.json({unix: unix_milli, utc: utc_milli})
  } else if (req.params.date == null) {
    console.log("Empty Date")
    res.json({unix: unix_empty, utc: utc_empty})
  } else {
    console.log('Try again :(')
    res.json({ error : "Invalid Date" })
  }
});



// listen for requests :)
var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});

// Receive request with date in url, read url, validate date, conver to unix and utc, send to re.json using req.queury.unix/utc
```

Comment: What is the output that you are getting? Do you have an idea of which line is causing the problem?

Comment: There are 2 example test cases, one which takes the input "2015-12-25" which returns the expected output, but the second case, "1451001600000", returns "{"unix":null,"utc":"Invalid Date"}" as its output. My guess is that the lines "regex_std = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/gm
  regex_un = /\d{0,}/gm" are causing the issue because without them, the code works fine. To specify, the inputs are in the for of express request parameters, and the regex is just used to validate the correct date input.